# Python: Why isn't "next()" called "__next__()"

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I'm using Python 2.7.

By convention, builtin methods like `__iter__`, `__init__`, `__str__`, etc. have the double underscore to identify them as such. Why doesn't the `next()` function have this?

It features alongside the other built-in functions here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html and this doesn't seem like a very consistent convention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The built-in function doesn't have `__` because none of the built-ins do. You're confusing built-ins (like `str`) with special methods (like `__str__`).

Now the special method called by the built-in `next` is also called `next` in Python 2.7, but that naming was recognized as an accident and changed to `__next__` in Python 3.

Comment: I see, this is apparent by the change in documentation from https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Answer (score 3):

It was in Python v3.x. And is still there for backwards compatibility. From http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html:

> Python 3 introduced a next() function to replace the next() method on
>   iterator objects. Rather than calling the method on the iterator, the
>   next() function is called with the iterable object as its sole
>   parameter, which calls the underlying `__next__()` method.